# Mysqli OOP query

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello I got this problem where my mysqli_query does not return any results.

```
    public static function Execute($query){ 
    self::$connection->query($query);
}
```

This is the function that I use for queries.

And this is the query itself;

```
$runtime = DataBase::Execute("SELECT SUM(runtime) runtime FROM test_tabela where user_id={Session::GetKey['user_id']} ");
```

But when I try to echo that result I get blank page.
Does any one know what's the problem because i can't find one maybe because I'm to tiered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't actually return anything.

Comment: Also your idea of adding variables into query is wrong. Prepared statement have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In your method you are not returning the [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object that are possibly being returned by [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). Just use `return`:

```
public static function Execute($query){ 
    return self::$connection->query($query);
}
```

Also I hope you sanitize `Session::GetKey['user_id']` as a session variable is generally considered *user input* which cannot be trusted like that. 
The [mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) also provides [parametrized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) which are much safer than simple string interpolation.